# Why does 0.0 == 0 means true in C language and when condition is 0.0 means false in branching statement?

Tags: c

```
// first
    bool flag = 0.0 == 0;
    printf("the flag of 0.0 == 0 is %d\n", flag);
```

it turns out:

```
    the flag of 0.0 == 0 is 1
```

run this program tell me 0.0 equals to 0, but the 0.0 is storged like 0.0e0, which is different from the int 0 storged.

```
// second
    if (!0.0) {
        printf("0.0 is false\n");
    }
```

the second program turns out

```
    0.0 is false
```

in branching statement, why 0.0 means the false, since my condition didn't do any operations which will convert its type to int 0

Comment: I don't understand the question. Why would `0.0` be different from `0`?

Comment: What in the output (which you did not share) leads you to conclude "0.0 equals to 0 means false in branching statement", and why?

Comment: There is no branching based on the result of `0.0==0` in your code. What do you mean?

Comment: sry, my question is not clear, i reedit my question.

Answer (score 2):

In `0.0 == 0` the `int` value it converted to `double` before the comparison is done (same as if you had written `0.0 == (double)0`).

```
      0.0 == 0
// double    int

// the int is converted to double by the usual arithmetic conversions
      0.0 == (double)0
```

See [C11 6.5.9](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.9): *"Any two values of arithmetic types from different type domains are equal if and only if the results of their conversions to the result type determined by the usual arithmetic conversions are equal"*

Answer (score 1):

> run this program tell me 0.0 equals to 0 means false in branching statement.

No.  The part of the program that reports on the result of `0.0 == 0` is this:

> ```
>     printf("%d", flag);
> ```

and it prints "1", which corresponds to true.  But the overall program output is deceptive, because you do not output anything to separate that "1" from the output of the next `printf()`.  The overall output is

```
10.0 is false
```

, where the first "1" digit comes from the first `printf` and reports on the comparison of `0` with `0.0`, and the rest, "0.0 is false", comes from the other `printf()` (because `0.0` indeed does evaluate to false in boolean context).

This would be clearer:

```
    bool flag = (0.0 == 0);

    printf("%d\n", flag);

    if (!0.0) {
        printf("0.0 is false\n");
    }
```

The output is:

```
1
0.0 is false
```

You go on to say,

> but 0.0 is double type, while 0 is int type, i just want to know why C treat the different type mean the same

For most operations on arithmetic types, instead of rejecting operations on operands of mixed types or performing any kind of analysis based directly on the presence of mixed types, the operands are converted to a common type and the operation applied to the converted arguments.  This even has a name and its own section in the standard: the "usual arithmetic conversions", C17 section 6.3.1.8.  The idea is that when such type mixtures occur, the expected behavior is normally to operate on the numeric values of the operands, not to make type-based distinctions.

In your example of `0.0 == 0`, the usual arithmetic conversions call for the `int` 0 on the right-hand side to be converted to type `double` to match the left-hand operand.  The result is exactly `0.0`, and the comparison evaluates to true (represented by the `int` value 1).

Comment: sry, my expresion are not clear. since i think integer and float point have different storge method, float point are storged in base with index 0.0e0. which seem to be different from int 0，so i think 0 should not equal to 0.0.

Comment: @pengxie, as this answer already explains, the comparison is performed after first bringing the two operands to a common type, therefore any difference in representation is irrelevant.  And in case it was unclear, that is a *value conversion*, not a reinterpretation of the representation, so converting `int` 0 to type `double` reliably results in exactly 0.0.

Answer (score 0):

Zero resolves to false, any other value resolves to true. This is specified by the standard of the language, see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion):

> The value zero (for integral, floating-point, and unscoped
> enumeration) and the null pointer and the null pointer-to-member
> values become false. All other values become true.

Once the standard is defined, it is followed.

Answer (score -4):

It is because '0.0' can hide something like '0.0001' and 0 is equals to 0, nothing more than 0.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: A literal `0.0` cannot be `0.0001`, so this answer doesn't really make sense.